# Icons for clearing / canceling / deleting?

Tags: icons

I have to design set of icons for 'clear search results', 'delete', 'close' and 'cancel' that due to specifics of the app might be sitting on the same toolbar side by side. Also the size is 16x16px which makes the task even more complicated.

So far I have a broom for the 'clear search results' which I dislike with a passion, "x" in a box for 'close', slashed circle for 'cancel' and nothing for 'delete'.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Location and size of the icons are not up to me, I just have to make them distinguishable so it's easier for the user to select right action from a choice of similar-looking icons.

Comment: I would suggest this is more a question for the Graphic Design SE. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JonW - Actually I think this has a good match with ux because of the potential for confusion to the user when having these four actions so close together. It's not just about pretty icons (no offence to gd :-) - it's about the meaning and clarity for the user and the relationship between these symbols. It's a tough problem.

Comment: It's a perfect example of where visual design and UX overlap quite a bit. My big concern would be placing those together. Even with perfectly designed visuals, I think there's a cognitive load trying to figure out "do I want to close this or cancel this? Or clear it?"

Comment: What is the difference between "close" and "cancel"? And are you also saving when you close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is always this conflict between clear-delete-close-cancel so these are the worst icons to have to position next to each other whilst still being able to determine which icon means what action.

**Considerations**

The only occurrence of red amongst the icons should be associated with the `delete` because this is the destructive action and should not be able to be easily confused with the other actions. A cross is best for `delete` and it doesn't need a box.

Because the `clear` is an action with a subject, try to include a cue as to what is being cleared (eg using the common magnifying glass for the *search* icon), this will help differentiate with the other icons

`Close` and `Cancel` need to be differentiated by the fact that the `cancel` might be undoing any changes made and therefore returning with no change, where as `close` will save any changes.

I would actually re-interpret your need for `close` and `cancel` to being '`accept with save`' and '`close-without-save`'

So `close` is like `Enter` on the keyboard - accepting any changes made, and we can use some symbology from the popular return/enter key on a keyboard.

`Close` should not indicate any acceptance. I'm slightly uncertain about using the cross as it is visually related to `delete` in this case, but either the cross (black) or the minus sign would suffice and with a box around it.

You have included delete as the second item, but actually because of the destructive nature of delete, I would ideally position it either:

- at least at one end to halve the likelihood of an accidental hit when going for either `clear` or `accept-with-save`
- preferably further separated from the other icons completely

**Results**

So here's the results after taking the above considerations on board:

[image]

[image]

Comment: As always - test icons *in context* and check your users understand them.

Comment: @ Roger Attrill - thank you so much for your detailed answer! Magnifying glass with 'x' in it was my first choice for 'clear search results' too, but it was rejected by the client, that's why i'm using broom.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a great guide to help make your icons more clear: [9 Rules to Make Your Icons Clear and Intuitive](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/9-rules-to-make-your-icons-clear-and-intuitive/)

Comment: Thanks, Wilson! I've add this to our [tag wiki for icon](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/icons/info).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is clarity, then I'm afraid that there are no icons for your situation which are going to suffice on their own.

Even a group of UX people don't have a uniform idea of what each icon means or what should represent it.  So you have to think beyond simple icons.  You need to include some text with the icon which makes it clear what it does.

When you're talking about a fairly **abstract concept**, unless there is a well defined icon for it, you **need to include text**.  If you don't, your design may be prettier but it's not going to be a better experience for your customers.

Comment: i agree with you, but there's no space on the widget's  toolbar to include text to explain function of each button :-/ there will be tooltip help bubbles, but one has to hover over the icon to see it. That's why i need to come up with distinguishable icons

Comment: There's always space for clarity if it's a high enough priority.  Outside of that, you aren't going to find what you want, just like I am not going to find a Ferrari for €1000 - even if that is my constraint.

Comment: If your contraints are that rigid - sometimes you just have to accept that you have to compromise on something else - like [period of ownership](http://www.northernferrarihire.com/ferrari_f430_coupe.htm) - enough to get the job done perhaps!

Comment: @RogerAttrill :)

Comment: @JohnGB & RogerAttill - and sometimes you have to "suck it up" and put a Ferrari sticker on the bumper of your beat-up Hyundai to prevent it from falling off :P